# Change typed form data to X's when typed

Tags: javascript, forms

Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish the following:

When a user types sensitive data into an html form, say their SSN or Bank Routing Number, how would I display X's for each character typed?

Said another way, if a user typed 888-123-4456, how can I code the input field to display xxx-xxx-xxxx as the user types in the data?

Would use javascript since its client side i'm assuming?

Any help would be very appreciated!
Jason

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, why not use

`<input type="password">`

Answer (score 0):

People are recommending `<input type='password'>`, which *will* obscure the display of the characters, and satisfy the requirements of your question.

But, if you're taking sensitive information from your customers, please make sure that you're **encrypting** all of this data before sending it over the wire, most likely by requiring https on your page.